# How to add another feature when NOT using panda dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, mysql-python

I am returning data from a table from mysql using the python api. the code below works for 1 feature. the return from the zip is a tuple of 1.

```
listtrain = twenty4hours.return_select("SELECT feature_1, class FROM justext")
f1, trgt = zip(*listtrain) 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(f1, trgt, random_state=0)
```

this code above is working.

```
listtrain = twent4hours.return_select("SELECT feature_1, feature_2, class FROM justext")
f1, f2, trgt = zip(*listtrain) 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(fX, trgt, random_state=0)
```

How do I add another feature/column so I can pass it to the function train_test_split? How do I build fX?  from f1 and f2.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling that I am turning in circle so right I will use panda DataFrame, after all this is made for this and there is ton of example online. I wanted to use list/tuple since the sql query API was returning one.

train_test_split() Allowed inputs are lists, numpy arrays, scipy-sparse matrices or pandas dataframes. [doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

Comment: Because I am using SQL I decided to use CONCAT(F1, F2) to have 2 input together. The accuracy is better. I will see if this improve the accuracy of the prediction if I CONCAT the string inputs with number inputs.